# insert image source name with random name in php

Tags: php

I am using PHP 7.2 image insert table name banner and field id, image, posted,
I have need image name with a random name like (Mohan-1274.jpg, Ravi-1236.jpg ) it's possible then help me please im share php code, database and HTML form here...

table name is banner

**currently save in a database**

```
id |  image      | posted

  1|  1234.jpg   | 06/06/2019

  2|  1254.jpg   | 06/06/2019

  3|  1236.jpg   | 06/06/2019

  4|  1274.jpg  | 06/06/2019
```

**have need data in a Database like this**

```
id |  image           | posted

  1|  amit-1234.jpg   | 06/06/2019

  2|  amit-1254.jpg   | 06/06/2019

  3|  ravi-1236.jpg   | 06/06/2019

  4|  mohan-1274.jpg  | 06/06/2019
```

`amit-1234.jpg` (1234 this is random name)

PHP insert pictute script

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))    
    $posted   = date('d-m-y');     
    $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['image'] ['name']);
    $image = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension[1];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    $folder = "vendors/banner/";

    move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$image);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into banner (posted,image) VALUES ('$posted','$image')");
}
```

HTML form

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"  placeholder="Banner Image" required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Whats the problem with your code currently? Do you receive an error?

Comment: I have currently received the file name 12345.jpg, 34567.jpg but  iiI have need insert image source name with a random name like Ravi-1236.jpg

Comment: Add a random string at the start of `$image`?

Comment: can you share this edited code

Comment: So where are those amit, ravi, mohan prefixes supposed to come from? Is that supposed to be a user name, part of the original file name, or … what?

Comment: original file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have file name available in $extension variable when you extracted file extension from the uploaded filename

```
$origname= $extension[0];
```

thereafter generating full filename to save could be

```
$image = $origname . rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension[1];
```

Then go ahead with remaining file processing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the faker library to get random names .
More on https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker